# Wait for key press but auto-start after time C++

Tags: c++, time, key, continue

I've seen this answered for other languages but not for C++. How would I get a program to wait for the user to press Enter or some key like that, but also to automatically continue after a set time period as long as a key hasn't been entered? I need basic code, I'm sort of a beginner. I know that cin.get(); or system("pause"); will wait for a key and sleep(x seconds); or Sleep(x milliseconds); (with the "windows.h" library) will pause a program, but how do I get both at once?

Answer (score 1):

In windows you can use `GetAsyncKeyState()` to poll the current state of the keyboard. Then you can use `Sleep()` to sleep a certain number of milliseconds. Combine those two and you can make something like what you need:

```
    int keyToWaitFor = VK_SPACE;
    int count = 0;
    int maxcount = 500;

    for(int a = 0; a < maxcount; a++){
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(keyToWaitFor)!=0){
            break;
        }

        Sleep(5);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you wizebin - I adapted it for Sleep(1) and maxcount=20000, but how could I use Enter? I suppose just replace int keyToWaitFor = VK_ENTER; ?

Comment: You can change the key to any virtual key, found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: This is a fairly poor method of doing the job. It burns CPU time while waiting for a key that hasn't been pressed, then wastes wall time after the key has been pressed before it detects/processes the input.

Comment: I disagree- especially for someone who has just started learning to program. I will agree that your method is better, but your claim of burning CPU time is unfounded. If you want to get more advanced in your polling why are you using the console instead of a GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Since you apparently want to do this on Windows, it's fairly straightforward.

You start by opening a handle to the console, such as with `GetStdHandle`. Then when you want to do a read, you call `WaitForSingleObject` on that handle, specifying your timeout value. Check the return. If the return value is `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, it means you have some input, which you can read with (for example) `ReadConsoleInput`. If the return is `WAIT_TIMEOUT`, it means there's no input, so you can do whatever else it is you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

With `conio.h`, You can wait for a keypress with `kbhit()` and `getch()` and make a wait for a 20 second timer with a 
while loop, `while( key==0 && (time_to_wait < secs) )`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int key=0;
bool quit=false;
void check_if_keypressed();
void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void clrscr();


int main() 
{
    clock_t start;
    double time_to_wait;
    double secs=10;

    gotoxy(1, 2);
    cout<<"Press any key to continue or wait 20 seconds:  \n ";

    start =  clock();

    while( key==0 && (time_to_wait < secs) )
    {
        check_if_keypressed();

        time_to_wait = (  clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    //  proceed with whatever here




        gotoxy(1, 23);
        cout<<"countdown: "<< secs-time_to_wait <<" \n ";
    }

    //  proceed with whatever here
    //  while( key!=27)
    //  {
    //    check_if_keypressed();
    //    do_other_stuff();
    //  }


    return 0;
}

void check_if_keypressed()
{
   if( kbhit() ) key=getch();

   switch(key)
   {
      case 27:
           quit=true;
       break;
   }

}


void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
    return;
}

void clrscr()
{
    COORD coordScreen = { 0, 0 };
    DWORD cCharsWritten;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    DWORD dwConSize;
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
    dwConSize = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, TEXT(' '), dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hConsole, csbi.wAttributes, dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coordScreen);
    return;
}
```